# List all file share from storage account using azure .net SDK or Fluent API?

Tags: c#, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk, azure-fluent-api

I want to show all file share from storage account. I have storage account dropdown so whenever user will select particular storage account name i want to fetch all file share name associated with selected storage account. I want any Fluent API or REST API.

Comment: Can .NET SDK or REST API both meet your requirements?

Comment: @Bowman Zhu currently In my project i am using azure fluent api but using that i am not able to fetch details of azure file share so I am finding any another way.So please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.Models;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

            ShareServiceClient ssc = new ShareServiceClient(connectionString);
            foreach (ShareItem item in ssc.GetShares())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-shares

**`.csproj`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.6.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but for ShareServiceClient class which nuget package should i install currently i have install Install-Package Azure.Storage.Files.Shares -Version 12.6.2 but not working

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya What did you get?

Comment: The type or namespace sound not be found . Are you missing assembly reference . But I installed properly and added reference also Azure.Storage.Files.Shares but still getting.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya I have updated the .csproj file.

Comment: Thank you very much........It's working now after build the project.

Comment: How to get Azure Storage Account Key (connectionString) any any .net sdk available for this also.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya Azure manage sdk should be able to do this. Do you mind to post a new question? Ask another question in the comment doesn't match community norms.